# TextViews disappear when using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want my application to re-establish a bluetooth connection when the screen orientation changes. I have a SavedState object that holds the BT serial service data, etc which I can save with onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and restore with getLastNonConfigurationInstance(), but my TextView fields are no longer updated when the orientation of the screen changes.

I have two xml files for the layout - one in layout-port and one in layout-land folders respectively to reformat the views. The TextView IDs are identical in both xml files, just their positions change.

If I comment out the call to the overridden onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(), the TextViews are visible again, but of course I can no longer reconnect to the BT device automatically.

The BT service is stopped when onDestroy() is called, so must be re-established each time the screen changes.

Having overridden calls to onRestoreInstanceState() and onSaveInstanceState() seem to have no effect.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? The disappearing views are permanent - ie changing from one orientation and back again does NOT restore the TextViews.

Comment: Don't use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance (and get). They are deprecated.

Comment: Are you using one activity or Fragments?

Comment: And… post some of your ACtivity (or fragment) code.

Answer (score 0):

When the device orientation changes, the views are taken off the screen (to be never shown again) and re-created. The same happens with the corresponding Activity. The now-invisible views and activity will be garbage-collected only when they are no longer referenced. The text in text views is preserved by the system, provided that the views have unique IDs. The fact that views are re-created means that you have to perform *findViewById()* again.

Now, from the MVC point of view, an `Activity` is a *Controller*. Your bluetooth connection definitely is a part of *Model* (it must survive orientation changes). So do not keep the bluetooth-related data in an `Activity`. You may use, say, a static variable, or a field in your `Application` subclass, or whatever else you find appropriate.
As to the MVC *View*, it is what you specify via XML; in principle, you can define your custom classes like `MyCustomButton`, but usually you just reuse the existing stuff.